# Python: Object() takes no parameters error, even when entire class module is indented properly

Tags: python, oop

I have created the class Book, and even though I wrote and indented the Book methods correctly (I actually copied the code 100% from my textbook), I cannot create a class instance. Here is my class:

```
class Book:
    """ Information about a book, including title, list of authors,
    publisher, ISBN, and price.
    """

    def __init__(self, title, authors, publisher, isbn, price):
        """ (Book, str, list of str, str, str, number) -> Nonetype

        Create a book, with a title, authors, publisher, isbn number, and price.

        >>> python_book = Book( \
                "Practical Programming", \
                ["Campbell", "Gries", "Montojo"], \
                "Pragmatic Bookshelf", \
                '000-1111', \
                25.0)
        >>> python_book.title
        "Practical Programming"
        >>> python_book.authors
        ["Campbell", "Gries", "Montojo"]
        >>> python_book.publisher
        "Pragmatic Bookshelf"
        >>> python_book.ISBN
        '000-1111'
        >>> python_book.price
        25.0
        """

        self.title = title
        self.authors = authors[:]
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.ISBN = isbn
        self.price = price

    def num_authors(self):
    """ (Book) -> int
        Return the number of authors for the book.
        """
    return len(self.authors)

    def __str__(self):
        """ (Book) -> str

        Return a human-readable string representation of this Book.

        """

        return "Title: {0}, Authors: {1}, Publisher: {2}, ISBN: {3}, Price: {4}".format(self.title, self.authors, self.publisher, self.ISBN, self.price)


    def __eq__(self, other):
        """ (Book, Book) -> bool

        Return True iff this book and other have the same ISBN.
        """

        return self.ISBN == other.ISBN
```

and here is my code in the shell:

```
>>> import book
>>> python_book = book.Book("Practical Programming", ["Campbell", "Gries", "Montojo"], "Pragmatic Bookshelf", '00-111', 25)
```

Even so, I get the "object() takes no parameters" error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong; like I said, I literally copied all of this code from my textbook, and still, I get an error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your return for the `num_authors` is indented wrong, but I assume you have it correctly on your code, so what version of python?

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the right file, and that you didn't accidentally redefine `Book` somewhere.

Comment: I see a few mixed tabs and spaces issues, particularly around the definition of `num_authors`. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor and see if you have any other mixed tabs and spaces that could be causing `__init__` to be outside the class definition or anything like that.

Comment: Did you edit the indentation in any way when you posted your code here?

Answer (score 2):

Your `num_authors` method is indented incorrectly. Both your help text and your `return` statement should be indented further than the `def`.

```
def num_authors(self):
""" (Book) -> int
    Return the number of authors for the book.
    """
return len(self.authors)
```

It should be

```
def num_authors(self):
    """ (Book) -> int
    Return the number of authors for the book.
    """
    return len(self.authors)
```

Make sure you do **NOT mix tabs and spaces**. Use one or the other, but not both at the same time, it interferes with python's ability to determine indentation level.

While the whole "tabs versus spaces" debate will go on forever, [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) strongly recommends spaces.

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.
>
> Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.
>
> Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively.

Get yourself a code editor that can automatically insert 4 spaces when you hit the <kbd>tab</kbd> key. [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), [Nodepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) or [Nodepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) are all good options.

Comment: Opening up the edit view shows that that's a mixed tabs and spaces issue.

Comment: @user2357112 I've updated my answer to include additional information about mixing tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly the issue you are facing? I ran this and it executed perfectly.

```
class Book:
""" Information about a book, including title, list of authors,
publisher, ISBN, and price.
"""

def __init__(self, title, authors, publisher, isbn, price):
    """ (Book, str, list of str, str, str, number) -> Nonetype

    Create a book, with a title, authors, publisher, isbn number, and price.

    >>> python_book = Book( \
            "Practical Programming", \
            ["Campbell", "Gries", "Montojo"], \
            "Pragmatic Bookshelf", \
            '000-1111', \
            25.0)
    >>> python_book.title
    "Practical Programming"
    >>> python_book.authors
    ["Campbell", "Gries", "Montojo"]
    >>> python_book.publisher
    "Pragmatic Bookshelf"
    >>> python_book.ISBN
    '000-1111'
    >>> python_book.price
    25.0
    """

    self.title = title
    self.authors = authors[:]
    self.publisher = publisher
    self.ISBN = isbn
    self.price = price

def num_authors(self):
    """ (Book) -> int
    Return the number of authors for the book.
    """
    return len(self.authors)

def __str__(self):
    """ (Book) -> str

    Return a human-readable string representation of this Book.

    """

    return "Title: {0}, Authors: {1}, Publisher: {2}, ISBN: {3}, Price: {4}".format(self.title, self.authors, self.publisher, self.ISBN, self.price)


def __eq__(self, other):
    """ (Book, Book) -> bool

    Return True iff this book and other have the same ISBN.
    """

    return self.ISBN == other.ISBN


python_book = Book("Practical Programming", ["Campbell", "Gries", "Montojo"], "Pragmatic Bookshelf", '00-111', 25)
print (python_book)
```

Output:

```
Title: Practical Programming, Authors: ['Campbell', 'Gries', 'Montojo'], Publisher: Pragmatic Bookshelf, ISBN: 00-111, Price: 25
```

Comment: I always get this error:



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#119>", line 1, in <module>
    python_book = book.Book("Practical Programming", ["Campbell"], "Pragmatic Bookshelf", '00-111', 25)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters





I'm actually not sure what the problem is. By all indications, it should work. I simply use the class module, type out the commands from the OP in the shell, and still get an error.

Comment: oh but it's working on mine. Which Python version are you using? Also if its not throwing error on 'import book' line then indentation and directory issue is not there. Is it throwing error on import line?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code after only declaring the def **init**() function, and it works fine. As mentioned in the other answers, check for the following:

1. Your indent for the num_authors() function
2. Whether the 'book' you are importing is in the same directory.